# Wordperss Custom Archive Template based on Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, templates, post, types, archive

I have added custom post type as "blog" and created single-blog.php. It is working fine but when I create archive-blog.php, it does not work. It is still going to default archive template.

I created custom taxonomy "blogcat" for custom post type "blog".

Can you please let me know why it is not reading archive-blog.php?

My permalink structure is post-name

Thanks,

Comment: Keep in Mind has_archive argument set to be true.
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/

This will help.

Comment: yes, has_archive already set to true. I am using custom taxonomy "blogcat" for custom post type "blog". May be this is the reason that it is going to default archive.php?

Answer (score 0):

To override the template for your custom taxonomy you have to use naming convention like this."taxonomyslug-archive.php"